# Changing a heading every few seconds, with an array and a loop

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to create a html heading that changes itself every 5 seconds, through an array of multiple items and a loop. I can get everything to work, except the text changing after every fifth second. Right now, it immediately goes from the first item in the array, to the last. I've tried using setTimeOut and setInterval, but no luck so far. I've also searched everywhere online.

Here's what i have so far, without the setTimeOut/setInterval part, because it didn't work:

```
var headingChange = {

  heading: function() {
      var headings = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Ye'];
      for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = headings[i];
      }
   }
};
```

Here's a jsfiddle to make it easier (+ html).

https://jsfiddle.net/countermb/w9qwk6ch/

Hope someone can help me (am new to Javascript). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you so with the setTimeout since that is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Snippet might help you.

You may need to use `setInterval` to change the heading.

```js
var headings = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Ye'];
var i = 0;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = headings[i];
  if (i == (headings.length - 1)) {
    i = 0;
    //you can even clear interval here to make heading stay as last one in array
    //cleanInterval(intervalId);

  } else {
    i++;
  }
}, 4000)
```

```html
<h1 id="heading">Change this!</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` to run your function every `n` milliseconds. Have also updated the snipped to just increment an index (or go back to 0) instead of looping through the array with a `for` loop.

```
var headingChange = {
  currentHeader: 0,
  headings: ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Ye'],
  heading: function() {
    document.getElementById('heading').innerHTML = this.headings[this.currentHeader];
    if (this.currentHeader === this.headings.length - 1) {
      this.currentHeader = 0;
    } else {
      this.currentHeader = this.currentHeader + 1;
    }
  } 
};

setInterval(function(){
  headingChange.heading();
}, 5000)
```